# How can I get the position of a child element not fixed even though the parent is fixed?

Tags: html, css, position, styles, fixed

As the title says: I need the 'info-box' to not be fixed while the head-box and head-in-block are fixed.

I know it is possible. I have a live example: http://www.marktplaats.nl/.
The orange box is fixed (head-box) then the white part (my info-box) is not fixed. And the Title block is fixed again (head-in-block).

This is the css and html I'm using right now. What adjustment needs to be made to make the middle (white) box not fixed?

```css
#head-block{
 width: 100%;   
 height: auto;
 background: rgb(245,245,245);
 border: 1px solid grey;
 z-index: 1000;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

#head-box{
 height: 5px; 
 background: #37326a; 
}

#info-box{
 height: 50px; 
 background: white; 
 position: static;
}

#head-in-block{
 width: 1100px;
 height: 60px;
 color: #37326a;
 text-align: left;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px;
}

.fixed{
 position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id='head-block' class='fixed'>
    <div id='head-box'></div>
    <div id='info-box'></div>
    <div id='head-in-block'>
    </div>
</div>

<div style='height: 1500px;' id='content'>
  
</div>
Test
```

[image: Marktplaats.nl]

Do you guys see the website the same I do?

Comment: that's not possible. Child elements always adhere to the positioning of their parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you linked to hides the white box when the header is sticky. So to do that here, you would hide `#info-box` when  `#head-block` has class `.fixed`

```
.fixed #info-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
#head-block{
 width: 100%;   
 height: auto;
 background: rgb(245,245,245);
 border: 1px solid grey;
 z-index: 1000;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

#head-box{
 height: 5px; 
 background: #37326a; 
}

#info-box{
 height: 50px; 
 background: white; 
 position: static;
}

#head-in-block{
 width: 1100px;
 height: 60px;
 color: #37326a;
 text-align: left;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px;
}

.fixed{
 position: fixed;
}
.fixed #info-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='head-block' class='fixed'>
    <div id='head-box'></div>
    <div id='info-box'></div>
    <div id='head-in-block'>
    </div>
</div>

<div style='height: 1500px;' id='content'>
  
</div>
Test
```

Comment: _"I know it is possible. I have a live example: http://www.marktplaats.nl/."_ you don't see the white box at all on this site when you scroll, either.

Comment: Sticky headers are always done via javascript, you cannot use a css-only solution. Without further examining the website, it can tell you it has a scoll eventhandler which toggles the positioning of the parent box and the display of the white box, depending on how far you scrolled.

Comment: @Christoph is that directed at me? I'm aware. JS adds the class `.sticky`. I'm assuming OP adds the class `.fixed` to this menu at some point, and wants to know how to exclude `#info-box` from being fixed in the header when `#head-block` has class `.fixed`. And like you said, you can't magically make a child element ignore its' parents position like that, but the technique on the site that OP linked to just hides the white box when the parent is fixed.

Comment: @MichaelCoker The orange box is on the website I referred to. I've added a screenshot of the website to clarify.

Comment: @LexdeWilligen everything orange in the screenshot you linked to stays fixed with the menu when it is sticky at the top of the viewport.